# AWS S3 generate_presigned_post loses content-type after formData POST

Tags: javascript, python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Using Python's boto3 library, I create a presigned URL and return it to the front end:

```py
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
response = s3_client.generate_presigned_post(
    "bucket",
    "logo",
    Fields={
        "Content-Type": "image/png"
    },
    Conditions=None,
    ExpiresIn=3600
)
```

...here's an example response:

```json
{
    "url": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket,
    "fields": {
        "Content-Type": "image/png",
        "key": "logo",
        "AWSAccessKeyId": "ABC",
        "policy": "blahblah",
        "signature": "XYZ123"
    }
}
```

I then use the response in the front end to POST the image to S3:

```js
const formData  = new FormData();
for (const key in json.fields) {
  formData.append(key, json.fields[key]);
}
formData.append("file", image);
return fetch(json.url, {
  method: "POST",
  body: formData
});
```

...which uploads the file as expected....except the Content-Type is reset to `binary/octet-stream`
[image]

How do I ensure that the Content-Type is `image/png` and not `binary/octet-stream`?

Comment: What happens if you include the Content-Type in the actual POST request? I'm not 100% sure how Content-Type in the signed URL Fields is used if it's not also supplied in the Conditions when signing.

Comment: Also afaik, the `formData.append('Content-Type', image.type);` would need to be before `formData.append("file", image);`.

Comment: @jarmod - Adding `formData.append('Content-Type', image.type);` results in an `Invalid according to Policy: Extra input fields: content-type` from AWS unfortunately.

Comment: It would need to be allowed in Conditions, e.g. `["starts-with", "$Content-Type", "image/"]`.

Comment: That might have fixed it....I'm now getting `image/png,image/png` as the Value of the Metadata. The problem I'm trying to solve is that after the upload, the browser is not rendering the newly uploaded image. I thought it was the `Content-Type`...maybe it's a race condition?

Comment: Please create a new post @timborden

Comment: New post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77947765/aws-generate-presigned-post-content-type-with-two-values