# AWS generate_presigned_post content-type with two values

Tags: javascript, python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Using Python's boto3 library, I create a presigned URL and return it to the front end:

```py
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
response = s3_client.generate_presigned_post(
    "bucket",
    "logo",
    Fields={
        "Content-Type": "image/png"
    },
    Conditions=[
        ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", "image/"],
    ],
    ExpiresIn=3600
)
```

...here's an example response:

```json
{
    "url": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket,
    "fields": {
        "Content-Type": "image/png",
        "key": "logo",
        "AWSAccessKeyId": "ABC",
        "policy": "blahblah",
        "signature": "XYZ123"
    }
}
```

I then use the response in the front end to POST the image to S3:

```js
const formData  = new FormData();
for (const key in json.fields) {
  formData.append(key, json.fields[key]);
}
formData.append("file", image);
return fetch(json.url, {
  method: "POST",
  body: formData
});
```

..which uploads the file as expected....except the Content-Type is set to `image/png,image/png`:
[image]

How do I ensure that the Content-Type is `image/png` and not `image/png,image/png`?

Comment: Turns out it wasn't an issue....there was a race condition that, once resolved, indicated that having multiple values is not an issue.